# How to add extra "end characters" to the "First sentence should end with a period." Checkstyle rule

Tags: eclipse, checkstyle

I'm trying to make it so that `:` is also a valid end of the line character.

Found out the rule is : [JavadocStyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_javadoc.html#JavadocStyle)  and the property endOfSentenceFormat however when i use the value listed as the default, i get an error in eclipse about parsing of the checkstyle file failing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking on the web, i found out that it's because the '<' from the default value ([.?!][ \t\n\r\f<])|([.?!]$) need to be escaped since it's an XML file. Didn't get an error as i was using a text editor myself.

So the value if i wanna add ":" as valid end of the line needs to be

```
 <module name="JavadocStyle">
    <property name="endOfSentenceFormat" value="([.?!:][ \t\n\r\f&lt;])|([.?!:]$)"/>
</module>
```

Hope it helps as there were not a whole lot of documentation.